# Justification for choice of beam stiffness at pinned far-end member

Tags: structural-analysis, beam, moments

I’m reading off an example provided by the ICE structural analysis book, specifically example 4.7 (moment distribution method) I dont seem to understand why the stiffness from member D-C is 4EI/L instead of 3EI/L.[image]